# jsoup not parsing HTML properly on android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am trying to extract links based on certain attributes using jsoup. The code works fine 
when I run it as a simple java program, but when I run it in Android I don't get results. The code I am running is as follows:

```
List<String> feeds = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/").get();
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("link");

    String type = "application/rss+xml";

    for (Element link : links) {
        if (link.attr("type").equals(type)) {
            //System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
            feeds.add(link.attr("href"));
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(String item : feeds){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

As a simple java code it is able to find a link to an RSS file on bbc.co.uk/news
but when I run it inside Android AsyncTask, I get no results. 
Any explanation?

Comment: Does your application have internet permission?

Comment: Yes it has internet permission

Comment: There's a good chance you're just not using Async task correctly.  Why don't you paste your Async task code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears the issue was with the default User-Agent. I applied @Niranjan solution and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a issue with `User-Agent`.
Try overriding the default `userAgent` like below

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/")
           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
           .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you get socket timeouts. Try to increase the timout value

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
```

Check your stack trace for `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`'s.

Comment: I tried that but there was no improvements, and exceptions were thrown either.

Comment: I even tried something else: instead of extracting only "application/rss+xml" links, I tried to extract all links. I got strange results: The plain java program returns all the links including one application/rss+xml . The android version also returns a number of links but this time the application/rss+xml is missing!